# Truncate text in an array of objects using vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

this is kind of building on a question that i asked yesterday. [Truncate Text in an array of object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736182/truncate-text-in-an-array-of-object?noredirect=1#comment103766133_58736182)

I wanna apply the same logic but using my vuex store. My store looks something like this:-

```
   state: {
     Data: []
         },
     getters: {
        getData:state => {
         const maxLength = 10;
          const resultArray = state.Data.map(i => {
           if (i.name <= maxLength) i.shortName = i.name;
            else {
           const shortenedName = i.name.substring(0, maxLength + 1);
         i.shortName = shortenedName + '...';
       }
       return i;
      });
       console.log(resultArray)
     }
         },
   mutations: {
     setData(state,payload) {
     state.Data = payload
        },
   const actions = {
setItems: (context, payload) => {
    if (payload) {
        context.commit("setData", payload);
        return;
    }
    else {
        Vue.$http.get(`https://example.com/getData`).then(
            (response) => {
                context.commit("setData", response.body);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
       }
    }
  }
```

So i am not sure how to apply the truncation logic on either my getter or setter which will return the desired array which i can use in my component using either `{{mapMutation}}` or `{{mapGetter}}`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where you put it depends on if you want the whole string and only display a part of it or don't care about the stuff you truncated. If you don't care, put it in the setter. But if you need the whole of the string but only want to display the first part, truncate it in the getter.

Comment: Yes, so i am setting it in the getter but i get undefined.

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out. Typos ughhh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 generic options:

Either you take the response from yesterday and you parse your Data before returning it on the get.

```
getters: {
  getData:state => {
    return parserSomeoneGaveYouInResponseToTheLastQuestion(state.Data)
  }
},
```

Or you can just apply the parse before saving the Data, just make sure you dont need the original Data

```
mutations: {
  setData(state,payload) {
     state.Data = parserSomeoneGaveYouInResponseToTheLastQuestion(payload)
  },
}
```

EDIT: just to clarify you either apply the parser on the mutation or on the getter, not in both.

Comment: I edited my code above and applied the logic on my getter but i get a console error saying it is undefined. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. And yes, i really should spend some time understanding identation as well.